# Best practice to create basics models in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, models, dao

I'm working on a NodeJS API project.
I have a lot of models (users, projects, team, ...) and for each of this model I have:

- Models methods (getters and setters)
- DB requests (I use Couchdb)
- Schema validation

My first question is:

### Should I create multiple modules for DB request and Class methods (in order to separate domain layer from persistance layer)?

My second question is:
"How should I manage the creation of a model?"
Multiple cases:

case 1 (init constructor with Id):

```
var user = new User({id: 1}); 
user.fetch(function(err, user) {
   user.get('name'); // George
});
```

case 2 (No constructor method):

```
user.fetchById({id: 1}, function(err, user) { 
   user.get('name'); // George
}
```

case3 (Differents modules DB and domain layer):

```
userDB.fetchById({id: 1}, function(err, data) { 
   var user = new User(data);
   user.get('name'); // George
}
```

Or maybe there is other best practice?
Note: I often see people making modules that represents models and that only expose DB requests.

Best regards.

Comment: One thing to strongly consider is that unless you have a dead simple data model, your underlying data may not actually reflect the way that your application models your data.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to web development, and I'm not sure to understand 100%. You mean that my application model does not reflect my database data?
thx for your answer